# node.js TypeError: undefined is not a function on app.get("/")

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying out node.js and some hello world examples and I'm getting this error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
   at c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TheBoard\TheBoard\server.js:10:13
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TheBoard\TheBoard\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at next (c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TheBoard\TheBoard\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TheBoard\TheBoard\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TheBoard\TheBoard\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TheBoard\TheBoard\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
   at Function.process_params (c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TheBoard\TheBoard\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
   at next (c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TheBoard\TheBoard\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
   at expressInit (c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TheBoard\TheBoard\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:33:5)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TheBoard\TheBoard\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Here's my code

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/",
    function(res, req) {
        res.send("<html><body><h1>Express</h1></body></html>");        
    });

app.get("/api/users",
    function(req, res) {
        res.send({ name: "Louis", isValid: true, group: "Admin" });
    });

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(3000);
```

I'm only getting the error when I hit http://localhost:3000/

I do not get any error when I hit http://localhost/api/users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem in a ordering of parameter.. req object doesn't have any send function.

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/",
    function(req, res) { 
        res.send("<html><body><h1>Express</h1></body></html>");        
    });

app.get("/api/users",
    function(req, res) {
        res.send({ name: "Louis", isValid: true, group: "Admin" });
    });

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function for **app.get("/")** is not correct. The order in which you have passed the arguments is not right. The correct way is to first give **request** object and then the **response** object. The correct way is to write like this:

```
app.get("/",
    function(req, res) {
    res.send("<html><body><h1>Express</h1></body></html>");        
    });
```

Hope this might work for you. :)